# Remote client for oracle on linux

Tags: linux, oracle

I need to drop remote oracle db  with *.sql script from linux env. How i can do that? Before I tried install sqlplus, but I could not install it...
There may be some other linux console client for oracle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot install sqlplus alone.

You need to install an Oracle client.

Choose you system [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/downloads/index.html), click on See All, and the client is the second link.

After that you sould add an entry in your tnsnames.ora file (located in $ORACLE_HOME/network/admin) and if you have connection to your remote server, sqlplus will work.

PS: Drop a oracle db is a strange operation to do. You need a dba to administration stuff.